# Are there any static JS concatenation/minification modules for Express.js?

Tags: concatenation, minify, express

I liked using the [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/) for compressing my CSS stylesheets.

Are there any modules, that, similarly to Stylus, can automatically compress and minify static JS files? I am looking for something to use with Express.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the assetmanager middleware: https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager

As far as I can tell, it uses jsmin for minifying the javascript: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

Answer (score 0):

This middlware provides minification for JS files: https://github.com/ncrohn/express-uglify

And this can do JS *and* CSS as well as some others: https://github.com/breeswish/express-minify

Its dependencies are listed [here](https://github.com/breeswish/express-minify/blob/master/package.json).  Both use uglify-js.

I found them by googling "minify middleware express".

Answer (score -1):

You can try Google's Closure Compiler.
You can find an online version here: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: No, that is not exactly what I need — afaik Closure Compiler runs on Java. I know that there is Uglify.js (built on Node.js), but I couldn't get it working it with Express.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. There is a REST API for the Closure Compiler, check it out here http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_api.html not sure if that would be any help either. I also believe Packer (http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) is written in Javascript, so maybe you could incorporate that.